# How many ways can we place 6 houseplants on 3 window seats

Tags: combinatorics

**How many ways can we place 6 houseplants on 3 window seats**

The correct answer should be: **20160**

My guess is that we should take 6! and multiply it with something?

6! = 720

So with that logic, 20160 / 720 = 28.

Where does 28 come from and why?

Comment: **Hint:** $28 = \binom{6+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{8}{2}$

Comment: The end result is that it matters how many plants are in the first window seat, how many plants are in the second window seat, and how many plants are in the third window seat.  An arrangement of $ab\mid cd\mid ef$ is different than an arrangement of $abc\mid~~\mid def$ for example.

Comment: @JMoravitz ... so similar to a stars and bars calculation where the stars are distinguishable but the bars are not, i.e. $\frac{(6+3-1)!}{(3-1)!}=20160$

Comment: Thanks JMoarvitz, i think in this case the houseplants are not distinguishable . But i guess that is solved by multiplying with 6! ?

Comment: The answer implies that the houseplants are distinguishable (*e.g. you have a cactus, a tulip, a bonsai tree, etc...*), that the window seats are distinguishable, and that the plants are lined up in a row on their respective window seats.  You could do it by picking how many plants are used per window seat and then picking which plant goes where as $\binom{6+3-1}{3-1}\cdot 6!$, or you could do it as arranging $abcdef\mid\mid$ in $\frac{8!}{2!}$ ways, or in other interpretations or orders of steps as well (*but those are the two that jump out to me most*)

Comment: Jesus to much for me :P anyways thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From the final answer, it seems that the plants are distinguishable, so are the windows, and the order in which they are placed also matters.
One way to tackle this would be to first, as you said, arrange them in $6!$ ways. Then one just needs to decide how to divide it into $3$ groups.
This is same as taking all the plants to be indistinguishable and dividing it into $3$  groups. Consider the boundaries between the window seats. You have to place the $2$ *boundaries* in between the plants. Thus, you need to arrange the $6$ plants and $2$ boundaries. This can be done in ${6+2\choose 2}=28$ ways. Now you just have to multiply by $6!$ to get the answer.

PS: Look into the technique 'stars and bars'. It is useful in solving many problems in combinatorics.